# Cuda to OpenCL conversion

Tags: c++, gpu, converter

Is there a tool or a lib or something that is capable of taking a Cuda file and convert it to OpenCL? It would be beneficial that it produces OpenCL code or code based on Opencl like SYCL.

Or should I consider a completely different route for the conversion. My issue is the current code is written in Cuda and I would need it in Open CL since it gives me hardware flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the very helpful [`AndiH/gpu-lang-compat`](https://github.com/AndiH/gpu-lang-compat) GitHub repo:

> [SYCLomatic](https://github.com/oneapi-src/SYCLomatic) translates CUDA code to SYCL code, allowing it to run on Intel GPUs; also, Intel's [DPC++ Compatibility Tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/dpc-compatibility-tool.html) can transform CUDA to SYCL.